# Android InAppBilling getSkuDetails returns null

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase, sku

I've been working on IAB V3, and have been having trouble, when trying to get the sku details off the store. After cheking for result failure of the inventory query, I try to get the details with inv.getSkuDetails(MODULE).getPrice(); This always returns null, and when debugging I can see that the inventory object is empty.

However These requests always return null.
I am aware that google requires you to upload an apk to the alpha release channel (and release it) and have the InAppPurchase active (I also gave the store a few days to take over the changes). To test I used the same APK as uploaded to the alpha channel.

The IabHelper obviously managed to connect to the right app, as a test purchase was possible, and could be queried from the store.

Code:

```
`mHelper = new IabHelper(MainActivity.this, getString(getString(R.string.key1));

                    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Problem Setting up Billing" + result);
                                return;
                            }

                            IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
                                    if (result.isFailure()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.connectionFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Log.d(TAG, result.getMessage() + result.getResponse() + inv.toString());
                                        return;
                                    }

                                       String modulePrice = inv.getSkuDetails(MODULE).getPrice();
                                       String moduleTitle = inv.getSkuDetails(MODULE).getTitle();
                                       String moduleDescription=inv.getSkuDetails(MODULE).getDescription();
                                    }
                            }

                            ArrayList<String> skuList=new ArrayList<String>();
                            skuList.add(MODULE);


                            try {
                                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
                            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });`
```

Ignore the wrong indentation and missing brackets, as i cut out some code.
I greatly appreciate any ideas as to what could be causing this problem.
Thanks